# How to fix 'AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__35_1() in _Layout.cshtml' in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I am working on an MVC application, and I am trying to add links to the navigation bar including a dropdown menu and a search form. But whenever I add the dropdown-items and the form to the navbar I am getting this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
> AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared__Layout.b__35_1() in _Layout.cshtml

When I remove the added code the program runs perfectly

_layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - eTickets</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/eTickets.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6KY5s6UI5J7SVYuZB4S/CZMyPylqyyNZco376NM2Z8Sb8OxEdp02e1jkKk/wZxIEmjQ6DRCEBhni+gpr9c4tvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">eTickets</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="badge-info bi-gear"></i>Management</a>

                           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Cinemas" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-camera-reels"></i> Cinemas</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Producers" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-headset"></i> Produers</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Actors" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-person-square"></i> Actors</a>

                            </div>
                           
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index"><i class="badge-info bi-film"></i>Movies</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Filter" style="padding-right:25px;">
                        <input name="searchString" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search movie..." />
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - eTickets - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ewfXo9Gq53e1q1+WDTjaHAGZ8UvCWq0eXONhwDuIoaH8xz2r96uoAYaQCm1oQhnBfRXrvJztNXFsTloJfgbL5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem, I'm using bootstrap 5.1.3 I also added the popper.js package and also the bootstrap package but the error still pops up.

Comment: Zero byte as first byte in your file strikes me as byte order mark (BOM) so make sure you save your file with utf-8 (as declared in your file) or without one. You might have copied some strange character from website and your text editor did its best to save the file using utf-32; you can do that in notepad++ VS VScode or you can sanitize your file by opening it in notepad (the windows one) and save it there it will drop or convert to strange characters anything it does not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, instead of using the div tag I replaced it with the ul tag

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="badge-info bi-gear"></i>Management</a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Cinemas" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-camera-reels"></i> Cinemas</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Producers" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-headset"></i> Produers</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Actors" asp-action="Index"> <i class="bi bi-person-square"></i> Actors</a></li>

                            </ul>
                           
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index"><i class="badge-info bi-film"></i>Movies</a>
                        </li>
```

and on the form I replaced the form tag with the div tag as follows

```
 <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Filter" style="padding-right:25px;">
                        <input name="searchString" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search movie..." />
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
```

Refer to the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/